# can't execute this latex source code

Tags: code, python, xymatrix, qcircuit

i've been drawing a quantum circuit using the qiskit package in python. i needed the latex source code and executed

```
circuit.draw(output='latex_source')
```

i got this very long line of latex code:

```
'% \\documentclass[preview]{standalone}\n% If the image is too large to fit on this documentclass use\n\\documentclass[draft]{beamer}\n% img_width = 6, img_depth = 15\n\\usepackage[size=custom,height=10,width=28,scale=0.7]{beamerposter}\n% instead and customize the height and width (in cm) to fit.\n% Large images may run out of memory quickly.\n% To fix this use the LuaLaTeX compiler, which dynamically\n% allocates memory.\n\\usepackage[braket, qm]{qcircuit}\n\\usepackage{amsmath}\n\\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}\n% \\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}\n% Comment out the above line if using the beamer documentclass.\n\\begin{document}\n\\begin{equation*}\n    \\Qcircuit @C=1.0em @R=0.0em @!R {\n\t \t\\lstick{ {q}_{0} : \\ket{0} } & \\gate{X} \\barrier[0em]{2} & \\qw & \\qw & \\qw & \\ctrl{1} & \\gate{H} \\barrier[0em]{2} & \\qw & \\meter & \\qw \\barrier[0em]{2} & \\qw & \\qw & \\ctrl{2} & \\qw & \\qw & \\qw\\\\\n\t \t\\lstick{ {q}_{1} : \\ket{0} } & \\qw & \\qw & \\gate{H} & \\ctrl{1} & \\targ & \\qw & \\qw & \\qw & \\meter & \\qw & \\ctrl{1} & \\qw & \\qw & \\qw & \\qw\\\\\n\t \t\\lstick{ {q}_{2} : \\ket{0} } & \\qw & \\qw & \\qw & \\targ & \\qw & \\qw & \\qw & \\qw & \\qw & \\qw & \\targ & \\control\\qw & \\meter & \\qw & \\qw\\\\\n\t \t\\lstick{c_{0}: 0} & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw \\cwx[-3] & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw\\\\\n\t \t\\lstick{c_{1}: 0} & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw \\cwx[-3] & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw\\\\\n\t \t\\lstick{c_{2}: 0} & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw & \\cw \\cwx[-3] & \\cw & \\cw\\\\\n\t }\n\\end{equation*}\n\n\\end{document}'
```

Please help me to distinguish the lines so that i can run this on latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need to do is inform the program that generated the single long string to create real newlines instead of outputting `\n`, and to output single `\` (backslash) characters instead of `\\` pairs. Oh, and it should get rid of the `\t` (tabbing) instructions too.

With these adjustments in place, and after (a) switching from the `standalone` to the `beamer` document class (as is suggested in the preamble comments) and (b) changing `@R=0.0em` to `@R=0.25em` (to increase the distance between rows), I get the following output:

[image]

```
%\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
% If the image is too large to fit on this documentclass use
\documentclass[draft,landscape]{beamer} % img_width = 6, img_depth = 15
\usepackage[size=custom,height=10,width=28,scale=0.7]{beamerposter}
% instead and customize the height and width (in cm) to fit.
% Large images may run out of memory quickly.
% To fix this use the LuaLaTeX compiler, which dynamically
% allocates memory.
\usepackage[braket, qm]{qcircuit}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}
\usepackage{geometry}
% Comment out the above line if using the beamer documentclass.
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\Qcircuit @C=1.0em @R=0.25em @!R {
\lstick{ {q}_{0} : \ket{0} } & \gate{X} \barrier[0em]{2} & \qw & \qw & \qw & \ctrl{1} & \gate{H} \barrier[0em]{2} & \qw & \meter & \qw \barrier[0em]{2} & \qw & \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \qw & \qw\\
\lstick{ {q}_{1} : \ket{0} } & \qw & \qw & \gate{H} & \ctrl{1} & \targ & \qw & \qw & \qw & \meter & \qw & \ctrl{1} & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw\\
\lstick{ {q}_{2} : \ket{0} } & \qw & \qw & \qw & \targ & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \qw & \targ & \control\qw & \meter & \qw & \qw\\
\lstick{c_{0}: 0} & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw \cwx[-3] & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw\\
\lstick{c_{1}: 0} & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw \cwx[-3] & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw\\
\lstick{c_{2}: 0} & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw & \cw \cwx[-3] & \cw & \cw\\
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```